# GTK3+ checking whether callback is connected to an object.

Tags: c, callback, gtk, gtk3

How do i check whether a given function is connected to an object via g_signal_connect ?

I'm using gtk+ 3.0 , code::blocks 13.12 ,ubuntu 14.04 and C as a programming language.

Answer (score 1):

You use [`g_signal_handler_find()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html#g-signal-handler-find), and its `G_SIGNAL_MATCH_FUNC` matching-mode.